# Limitations of Elliptic Curve Cryptography?

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves

Simple question, what are the limitations of ECC, both in terms of application and how secure it is?

I heard that the NSA were able to read emails a few years back due to a backdoor they had discovered on a particular NIST elliptic curve. Is this something we can continue to expect, and what other potential drawbacks exist?

Comment: "*I heard that the NSA were able to read emails a few years back due to a backdoor they had discovered on a particular NIST elliptic curve.*" - If you're referring to DUAL_EC_DRBG, that wasn't a curve but a random number generator based on elliptic curves (that works with all elliptic curves)

Comment: The main part of your question, about backdoors, seems to be answered by [these](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10263/should-we-trust-the-nist-recommended-ecc-parameters) two [questions](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12898/is-there-a-feasible-method-by-which-nist-ecc-curves-over-prime-fields-could-be-i).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a rather open ended question, but I'll try to answer:

Limitations:

- most ECDSA implementations require a secure random generator - if the same random value is reused (for different plaintext) then the private key parameter can simply be calculated;
- ECDSA requires a hash function and cannot be (easily?) used for signatures with message recovery (then again, the signatures are generally much smaller than e.g. RSA in the first place);
- ECC doesn't provide a direct method of encryption, instead EC-IES is commonly used - which means that that a key pair generation has to be performed and that the public key must be send along with the ciphertext;
- ECC is much more efficient than RSA for signature generation and decryption, but it's still much slower than symmetric algorithms;
- ECC requires some agreement on which type of curve and curve parameters to use;
- support for ECC - especially more modern curves - is lacking from many libraries.

Security:

- the fact that the calculations can be performed on relatively small integers (compared to e.g. DH/DSA or RSA) makes the algorithm rather efficient but it may also help quantum crypto-analysis;
- many curves - such as the most used curves by NIST over prime fields - require additional verification of the public key to be performed;
- RSA is much easier to understand than ECC (and a better understanding aids the security of protocols and implementations);
- RSA is *still* much better researched, e.g. with regards to side channel attacks.

Comment: Minor correction to limitation 1: we know how to generate ECDSA signatures securely without a random number generator, for example, see RFC 6979 for one such way

Comment: @poncho Yeah, it's known but not much used, I've changed the wording. There is a bit of an issue with answering questions like these; how much of lesser known protocols and algorithms should be considered? It's hard to include *everything* and if you do include special constructs then the user will find out that most libraries do not provide the functionality required...