# Kleptographic attack of ECDSA key generation?

Tags: elliptic-curves, key-generation, backdoors

Kleptographic attacks can be designed for RSA key generation, Diffie–Hellman key exchange, DSA/ECDSA signing, etc. Is it also possible for ECDSA key generation?

More detailed: Is it possible for an attacker to design an ECDSA key generation algorithm, for which the attacker can easily derive the private keys of all generated public keys, while nobody else has any advantage in getting the private keys? (and even nobody else could distinguish public keys generated this way from other public keys)

**Edit:**

I'm talking about key generation on a specified curve (such as secp256k1), rather than adding backdoors into ECC parameters. What I am looking for is an ECDSA version of this answer: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/32155/58843

Comment: [Is there a feasible method by which NIST ECC curves over prime fields could be intentionally rigged?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12898/18298) [Should we trust the NIST-recommended ECC parameters?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/10263/18298) [Hide a weakness in ECC by choosing the prime or one of the curve coefficients](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/10292/18298)

Comment: [search on elliptic curve backdoor](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=elliptic+curve+backdoor)

Comment: @kelalaka My question is different from the one you mentioned. I have edited the question.

Comment: Like the NIST Dual EC DRBG? [Proving Non-Existence of ECC Backdoors](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18818/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka I'm talking about key generation on a specified curve, rather than adding backdoors into ECC parameters

Comment: @kelalaka I know exactly what the backdoor of Dual EC DRBG does. My question is similar to that, but they are different. What I am looking for is an ECDSA version of this answer: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/32155/58843